# How to make sure that the code is executed every 10 minute, for an infinite time?

Tags: android, android-intent, http-post, android-service, alarmmanager

I have been trying to run a particular function every ten minutes, for an infinite time, however, it stops after about 60-90 minutes. This is despite the fact that I am making use of Alarm Manager and a Service to make sure that the App is not killed by the OS. I have even checked in the cellphone, in Settings-> Manage App -> Running and it shows that 1 Process and 1 Service of my App is running, yet the particular function stops to run after some time.

In the MainActivity, inside onCreate(), this is how I am calling the service:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
startService(i);
```

This is what my Service class looks like:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
//Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
Alarm alarm;
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();       
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{   
    alarm = new Alarm();
    alarm.SetAlarm(MyService.this);
    Log.i("Called alarm.SetAlarm","Called alarm.SetAlarm");
     return START_STICKY;
}

public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId)
{   alarm = new Alarm();
    Log.i("Called alarm.SetAlarm(context)","Called alarm.SetAlarm(context)");
    alarm.SetAlarm(context);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;
}
}
```

This is what my Alarm Manager looks like. The function that needs to be executed after every 10 minutes is UpdataData(), which is also being called here in onReceive().

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
 {    
public MainActivity obj;
//public MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{   
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)          
    context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl =
    pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();
    obj = new MainActivity();
    //UpdataData() needs to be executed after every 10 minutes, for an     
    //  infinite time
    obj.UpdateData();
    // Put here YOUR code.
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); e
    //MainActivity.UpdateData(context);
    wl.release();
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    Log.i("Inside SetAlarm","Inside SetAlarm");
    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
}
```

Also note that every ten minutes, the cellphone's screen splashes with the Toast text "Alarm!!!!" and the UpdataData function is called as well for good 60 -90 minutes. However, post this, the call stops and I don't know why. I would be very thankful if someone could help.

This is what my UpdataData() looks like:

public void UpdateData() {

```
    Log.i("Inside Update Data", "Inside Update Data");

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
         for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
                try {

                    // Your code goes here
                    if (locationclient != null
                            && locationclient.isConnected()) {
                        loc = locationclient.getLastLocation();
                        lat = loc.getLatitude();
                        lng = loc.getLongitude();

                    }

                    /*SharedPreferences settings = con.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Log.i("SP UD", "SP UD");
                     if(settings.contains("token")){
                        token = settings.getString("token", null);
                        Log.i("Inside SP UD", "token: "+token);
                    }*/

                    try { // Updating the latest location in the UI, just
                            // for convinience.
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        // Creating HTTP Post
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                                "http://www.website.com/update");
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                                3);
                        // Building post parameters//
                        // key and value pair
                        Log.i("token", "token" +token);

                        Log.i("Latitude for III POST Call",
                                "Latitude for III POST Call" + lat);
                        Log.i("Longitude for III POST Call",
                                "Longitude for III POST Call" + lng);
                        if(lat == 10 && lng == 10){
                            loc = locationclient.getLastLocation();
                            lat = loc.getLatitude();
                            lng = loc.getLongitude();
                        }


                        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",
                                token));
                        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",
                                Double.toString(lat)));
                        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",
                                Double.toString(lng)));
                        Log.i("Made UpdateData Post Call",
                                "Made UpdateData Post Call");
                        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
                        try {
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                                    nameValuePair));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            // writing error to Log
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Making HTTP Request
                        try {
                            HttpResponse response = httpClient
                                    .execute(httpPost);

                            // writing response to log
                            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                            // Your code goes here
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // writing exception to log
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }// While closed

        }

    });
    thread.start();
    }// UpdateData closed
```

Comment: Do **not** create instances of components yourself. With respect to your code, do not create instances of an activity (`new MainActivity()`) or receiver (`new Alarm()`). Only the framework creates those objects. In addition, do not perform network I/O or disk I/O on the main application thread, and do not do that work in some bare thread forked by a `BroadcastReceiver` (as Android may terminate your process before the work is done). Delegate that work to an `IntentService`, using a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to arrange to keep the device awake while that work is going on.

Comment: Beyond all that, use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see if your alarms are still scheduled. Bear in mind that on API Level 19+ devices, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, `setRepeating()` is intrinsically inexact.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks a lot for your response. So, all the POST call that I am making, should be made in an IntentService? Also, it would be extremely nice of you, if you could please give me some example with code as I am new to Android development. Would be very thankful to your help.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, as stated above a different approach is most likely required:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I did as both of you suggested, however, the IntentService is being killed after some time and this leads to stoppage of data from App to the Server.  Regarding this, I have posted a question, it would be extremely nice, if any of you could please answer it. Here is the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334215/how-to-keep-the-cpu-of-android-phone-always-awake